# Using Typeahead with json source

Tags: jquery, typeahead

so, I'm trying to get the typeahead up and running. I added the sources and jquery to my project and started with the following:

```
var countries = ["a list of countries","USA","Germany","Austria", "others"];

$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    source: countries
});
```

Since this is working I know the typeahead itself works.

When I use the example on the website however, I'm unable to get in working with a server side json.

The Code I'm using:

```
      $("input.typeahead").typeahead({
           onSelect: function(item) {
               console.log(item);
           },
           ajax: {
               url: "/backend/getsearchbox",
               timeout: 500,
               displayField: "label",
               valueField: "value",
               triggerLength: 3,
               method: "get",

               preDispatch: function (query) {

                   return {
                       search: query
                   }
               },
               preProcess: function (data) {

                   if (data.success === false) {
                       // Hide the list, there was some error
                       return false;
                   }
                   // We good!
                   return data.mylist;
               }
           }
       });
```

when using the chrome inspect tool under Network I see my request in the List

```
Request URL: https://domain.tld/backend/getsearchbox?search=aust
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200
```

When I access the link itself with the search query I have the following result:
EDIT: My Mistake. The JSON had an error:

```
[{"label":"Austria","value":"Austria Value"},{"label":"Australia", "value":"Australia Value"}]
```

So, according to my understanding it should be working. Yet, I don't get any results. Nor do I get errors from the console itself.

Thankful for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

I think your structure of JSON object is wrong at position 1

it should have same JSON object structure

```
[{"label":"Austria","value":"Austria Value"},{"Australia":"Australia Value"}]
```

If you look at array index `1` its have values without key. and as per typehead its much have `label & value` because you provided in settings

```
 displayField: "label",
 valueField: "value",
```

So You need to create structure from server with proper key and value or you can do it after response by `preProcess` function.

So finally correct response should be look like

```
[{"label":"Austria","value":"Austria Value"},
{"label":"Australia":"value":"Australia Value"}, 
{"label":"India","value":"India Value}]
```

Comment: sorry, yeah. instead of countries I have personal data in them so I edited it. The json is always with lable and value.

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing the JSON string with JSON.parse(),
this worked for me

```
var countries = [];
countries = JSON.parse(data.mylist);

$('.typeahead').typeahead({
   source: countries
});
```

Comment: how would I define data.mylist? as a json response

Comment: I meant that you should parse the response,

Comment: I meant that you should parse the response, I thought that you could parse data.mylist, and save it in the countries global variable, then you could use it in source of typeahead, I did something similar in angular 6. But I'm sure that jQuery is similar, (You will need to use the `$('.typeahead').typeahead({
   source: countries
});` only after you'll get the response from the server)

Comment: yeah, I know what you mean, I just don't know how to do it. I have no idea how to get this done outside of the typeahead function